# 'Inbox by gmail' styled opening and closing transition for an email (Android)

Tags: android-transitions, google-inbox

Can anyone suggest me an example for the opening and closing transition that is used in Inbox by Gmail's Android App.

I did manage to find [this](https://github.com/zhaozhentao/InboxLayout) example. However, is there anything else available?

Comment: have you find anything?